# How to check an IEnumerable for multiple conditions with a single enumeration without buffering?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I have a very long sequence of data is the form of `IEnumerable`, and I would like to check it for a number of conditions. Each condition returns a value of true or false, and I want to know if all conditions are true. My problem is that I can not afford to materialize the `IEnumerable` by calling `ToList`, because it is simply too long (> 10,000,000,000 elements). Neither I can afford to enumerate the sequence multiple times, one for each condition, because each time I will get a different sequence. I am searching for an efficient way to perform this check, using the existing LINQ functionality if possible.

---

**Clarification:** I am asking for a general solution, not for a solution of the specific example problem that is presented bellow.

---

Here is a dummy version of my sequence:

```
static IEnumerable<int> GetLongSequence()
{
    var random = new Random();
    for (long i = 0; i < 10_000_000_000; i++) yield return random.Next(0, 100_000_000);
}
```

And here is an example of the conditions that the sequence must satisfy:

```
var source = GetLongSequence();
var result = source.Any(n => n % 28_413_803 == 0)
    && source.All(n => n < 99_999_999)
    && source.Average(n => n) > 50_000_001;
```

Unfortunately this approach invokes three times the `GetLongSequence`, so it doesn't satisfy the requirements of the problem.

I tried to write a Linqy extension method of the above, hoping that this could give me some ideas:

```
public static bool AllConditions<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    params Func<IEnumerable<TSource>, bool>[] conditions)
{
    foreach (var condition in conditions)
    {
        if (!condition(source)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This is how I intend to use it:

```
var result = source.AllConditions
(
    s => s.Any(n => n % 28_413_803 == 0),
    s => s.All(n => n < 99_999_999),
    s => s.Average(n => n) > 50_000_001,
    // more conditions...
);
```

Unfortunately this offers no improvement. The `GetLongSequence` is again invoked three times.

After hitting my head against the wall for an hour, without making any progress, I figured out a possible solution. I could run each condition in a separate thread, and synchronize their access to a single shared enumerator of the sequence. So I ended up with this monstrosity:

```
public static bool AllConditions<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    params Func<IEnumerable<TSource>, bool>[] conditions)
{
    var locker = new object();
    var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();
    var barrier = new Barrier(conditions.Length);
    long index = -1;
    bool finished = false;

    IEnumerable<TSource> OneByOne()
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                TSource current;
                lock (locker)
                {
                    if (finished) break;
                    if (barrier.CurrentPhaseNumber > index)
                    {
                        index = barrier.CurrentPhaseNumber;
                        finished = !enumerator.MoveNext();
                        if (finished)
                        {
                            enumerator.Dispose(); break;
                        }
                    }
                    current = enumerator.Current;
                }
                yield return current;
                barrier.SignalAndWait();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            barrier.RemoveParticipant();
        }
    }

    var results = new ConcurrentQueue<bool>();
    var threads = conditions.Select(condition => new Thread(() =>
    {
        var result = condition(OneByOne());
        results.Enqueue(result);
    })
    { IsBackground = true }).ToArray();
    foreach (var thread in threads) thread.Start();
    foreach (var thread in threads) thread.Join();
    return results.All(r => r);
}
```

For the synchronization a used a [`Barrier`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.barrier). This solution actually works way better than I thought. It can process almost 1,000,000 elements per second in my machine. It is not fast enough though, since it needs almost 3 hours to process the full sequence of 10,000,000,000 elements. And I can't wait for the result for longer than 5 minutes. Any ideas about how I could run these conditions efficiently in a single thread?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are looking for a solution that only needs one enumeration over your sequence? How much does it matter to you that the solution can apply to other cases? Because it doesn't seem too complicated to write the parsing yourself that checks for these specific three conditions in one parse.

Comment: @CorentinPane I am searching for a general solution, so that I can use it with any number and variety of conditions. Doing the parsing myself with custom code is doable but time consuming and error prone, and I will have to do it again when the next set of conditions is requested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to ensure that the sequence is enumerated only once, conditions operating on the whole sequence are not useful. 
One possibility that comes to my mind is to have an interface which is called for each element of the sequence and implement this interface in different ways for your specific conditions:

```
bool Example()
{
    var source = GetLongSequence();

    var conditions = new List<IEvaluate<int>>
    {
        new Any<int>(n => n % 28_413_803 == 0),
        new All<int>(n => n < 99_999_999),
        new Average(d => d > 50_000_001)
    };

    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        foreach (var condition in conditions)
        {
            condition.Evaluate(item);
        }
    }

    return conditions.All(c => c.Result);   
}

static IEnumerable<int> GetLongSequence()
{
    var random = new Random();
    for (long i = 0; i < 10_000_000_000; i++) yield return random.Next(0, 100_000_000);
}

interface IEvaluate<T>
{
    void Evaluate(T item);
    bool Result { get; }
}

class Any<T> : IEvaluate<T>
{
    private bool _result;
    private readonly Func<T, bool> _predicate;

    public Any(Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        _predicate = predicate;
        _result = false;
    }

    public void Evaluate(T item)
    {
        if (_predicate(item))
        {
            _result = true;
        }
    }

    public bool Result => _result;
}


class All<T> : IEvaluate<T>
{
    private bool _result;
    private readonly Func<T, bool> _predicate;

    public All(Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        _predicate = predicate;
        _result = true;
    }

    public void Evaluate(T item)
    {
        if (!_predicate(item))
        {
            _result = false;
        }
    }

    public bool Result => _result;
}

class Average : IEvaluate<int>
{
    private long _sum;
    private int _count;
    Func<double, bool> _evaluate;
    public Average(Func<double, bool> evaluate)
    {
    }

    public void Evaluate(int item)
    {
        _sum += item;
        _count++;
    }

    public bool Result => _evaluate((double)_sum / _count);
}
```

Comment: Another optimization opportunity - depending on the number and complexity of the conditions -  might be to call the `Evaluate` methods of all the condition objects in parallel.

Comment: its a lot of code to do three simple checks across an array.

Comment: @TimRutter I understood the OP wants a rather generic approach. For specific cases this can for sure be done with much less code as Corentin's answer shows.

Comment: Yes, i wasn't  saying it was a bad approach the OP would need to consider whether such genericness is worth the weight of extra code.  Which it may well be if their checks are variable or complex enough, or user configurable.  I actually wrote something very similar to the above just recently!

Comment: Your `AverageGreaterThan._count` should be a `long`, and `_sum / _count` should probably be `(double) _sum / (double) _count`.

Comment: Thanks Klaus for the answer. Your approach is quite interesting, but it's not generic enough. If I follow this path I should have to rewrite half the LINQ library, multiplied by 2 or 3 variants for each built-in method: `AnyDivisibleBy`, `AnyNonDivisibleBy`, `AllLessThan`, `AllNonLessThan`, `AllEqualTo`, `AllNonEqualTo`, `AverageGreaterThan`, `AverageGreaterOrEqualThan`, `AverageNonGreaterThan` etc. That's a lot of work to do, with all the unit tests I'll have to write. Honestly I was hoping to leverage the existing functionality of LINQ, but I guess it's not possible.

Comment: Performance-wise your solution is 9 times faster than my multi-threaded attempt, which is very nice! Now I am down from 3 hours to 20 minutes. Since your code seems already optimal, I guess I should look for a faster machine to get the 5 min performance I need!

Comment: Regarding parallelization, in my case the evaluation of each element is very cheap. It involves one or two mathematical operations on average. So parallelizing the `Evaluate` calls should not offer any benefits. It could become viable if each evaluator could work with a batch of elements, if I could manage to do the batching somehow.

Comment: I generalized the code so that you might be able to re-use the LINQ expressions you already have. Your batching idea sounds promising.

Comment: Wow! That's great! I really like it. For some reason converting the `conditions` from `List` to array speeds up the execution by almost 2x. Now we are down to only 12 minutes for 10,000,000,000 items. :-)

Comment: I changed the `Evaluate` method of the `IEvaluate<T>` interface from `void Evaluate(T item)` to void `Evaluate(T item, ref bool completed, ref bool cancel)`. The parameter `completed` is used by the method `Any` when the condition is satisfied, to remove itself form the list of conditions, so that the enumeration can continue faster. The parameter `cancel` is used by the method `All` when the condition can never be satisfied, to stop the enumeration altogether.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is check for these three conditions on a single thread in only one enumeration, I wouldn't use LINQ and manually aggregate the checks:

```cs
bool anyVerified = false;
bool allVerified = true;
double averageSoFar = 0;

foreach (int n in GetLongSequence()) {
    anyVerified = anyVerified || n % 28_413_803 == 0;
    allVerified = allVerified && n < 99_999_999;
    averageSoFar += n / 10_000_000_000;
    // Early out conditions here...
}
return anyVerified && allVerified && averageSoFar > 50_000_001;
```

This could be made more generic if you plan to do these checks often but it looks like it satisfies all your requirements.

Comment: Thanks Corentin for the answer. Performance-wise your solution is excellent. It processes the whole sequence of 10,000,000,000 numbers in 4.5 minutes! Unfortunatelly this kind of manual coding is error prone. For example your calculation of the average makes the assumption that the sequence will have exactly 10,000,000,000 elements, which is not a given. The sequence length may vary. Even if the length was fixed, I think that summing partial averages will still give finally an incorrect result.

Answer (score 0):

Can I also suggest you another method based on the `Enumerable.Aggregate` LINQ extension method.

```cs
public static class Parsing {
    public static bool ParseOnceAndCheck(this IEnumerable<int> collection, Func<int, bool> all, Func<int, bool> any, Func<double, bool> average) {
        // Aggregate the two boolean results, the sum of all values and the count of values...
        (bool allVerified, bool anyVerified, int sum, int count) = collection.Aggregate(
            ValueTuple.Create(true, false, 0, 0),
            (tuple, item) => ValueTuple.Create(tuple.Item1 && all(item), tuple.Item2 || any(item), tuple.Item3 + item, tuple.Item4 + 1)
        );
        // ... and summarizes the result
        return allVerified && anyVerified && average(sum / count);
    }
}
```

You could call this extension method in a very similar way than you would usual LINQ methods but there would be only one enumeration of your sequence:

```cs
IEnumerable<int> sequence = GetLongSequence();
bool result = sequence.ParseOnceAndCheck(
    all: n => n < 99_999_999,
    any: n => n % 28_413_803 == 0,
    average: a => a > 50_000_001
);
```

Comment: Thanks again Corentin. This solution produces correct results, and offers a nicer API compared to your [previous solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58578826/11178549). Regarding performance it is 3 times slower, which is a price I am willing to pay in order to gain a generality of usage. Unfortunately your solution is not generic at all. It can only be used with `int` sequences, and can check for 3 conditions only, which must be exactly one `all`, one `any` and one `average`. So it is not an acceptable solution to my problem. But thanks again for trying to help! :-)

Comment: This seems to be both an efficient and functional way to answer my similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61423115/is-it-possible-to-simplify-the-following-linq-expression) though

Answer (score 0):

I found a single-threaded solution that uses the [Reactive Extensions library](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive). On the one hand it's an excellent solution regarding features and ease of use, since all methods that are available in LINQ for `IEnumerable` are also available in RX for [`IObservable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iobservable-1). On the other hand it is a bit disappointing regarding performance, as it is as slow as my wacky multi-threaded solution that is presented inside my question.

---

**Update:** I  discarded the previous two implementations (one using the method [`Replay`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/replay.html), the other using the method [`Publish`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/publish.html)) with a new one that uses the class [`Subject`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html). This class is a low-level combination of an `IObservable` and `IObserver`. I am posting to it the items of the source `IEnumerable`, which are then propagated to all the `IObservable<bool>`'s provided by the caller. The performance is now decent, only 40% slower than Klaus Gütter's [excellent solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58578875/11178549). Also I can now break from the loop early if a condition (like `All`) can be determined to be false before the end of the enumeration.

```
public static bool AllConditions<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    params Func<IObservable<TSource>, IObservable<bool>>[] conditions)
{
    var subject = new Subject<TSource>();
    var result = true;
    foreach (var condition in conditions)
    {
        condition(subject).SingleAsync().Subscribe(onNext: value =>
        {
            if (value) return;
            result = false;
        });
    }
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        if (!result) break;
        subject.OnNext(item);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Usage example:

```
var result = source.AllConditions
(
    o => o.Any(n => n % 28_413_803 == 0),
    o => o.All(n => n < 99_999_999),
    o => o.Average(n => n).Select(v => v > 50_000_001)
);
```

Each condition should return an `IObservable` containing a single boolean value. This is not enforcible by the RX API, so I used the `System.Reactive.Linq.SingleAsync` method to enforce it at runtime (by throwing an exception if a result doesn't comply to this contract).