# Is it possible to simplify the following Linq expression?

Tags: c#, linq

I have to maintain a code that makes a comparison between the items of two collections

```
list1.Where(item1 => list2.Any(item2 => Cond1(item1,item2)) &&
    !list2.Any(item2 => Cond2(item1,item2)) 
)
```

I was trying to simplify all those iterations and I wondered whether the above code is equivalent to the following

```
list1.Where(item1 => list2.Any(item2 => Cond1(item1,item2) && !Cond2(item1,item2)))
```

That seems more manageable, so I tried with some test cases and the initial results were ok. Do you think that it is true in general or can you spot a situation where the first, longer code is needed (=different from the second, shorter one)?

### Edit to reflect comments

Some interesting notes from the comments.

1. the above seems to be equivalent if and only if `Cond1` determines a unique key condition for `list2`, but of course this is not true in the general case.
2. inverting the order of the two `Any` statement appears to be more efficient as [pointed out by Knoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61423115/is-it-possible-to-simplify-the-following-linq-expression#comment108660125_61423115).

Regarding point 2, please consider that a more realistic business code would be

```
list1.Where(item1 => list2.Any(item2 => Cond1(item1,item2)) &&
    !list2.Any(item2 => Cond1(item1,item2) && Cond2(item1,item2)) 
)
```

because the typical business problem described here is comparing 2 collections and looking for missing, matching and different records, the latter (different - but not missing - records) being what is reported in the question

Comment: Second statement and first statement are not same. They will give different results in different situation

Comment: The first one does not compile. You can't declare `item2` two times. Please provide code that actually runs

Comment: Apologies, missed the closing bracket. You're absolutely right

Comment: That said ajay ghandi is correct. They can give different results. Lets say in the second `Any` `item2` is called `item3`, it's now easier to see that `item2` and `item3` can be different items. So basically the first one says "is there any item in list1 where there is an item in list2 that fullfills Cond1 but no item in list2 that fullfills Cond2?" The second one would say "Is there any item in list1 where there is an item in list2 that fullfills Cond1 but not Cond2"(so it has to be the same item in list2)

Comment: Not the complete answer. For example it would also be interesting to note that if you change the order (first the not `Any` and then the `Any` the code becomes more efficient. That said due to illness I'm on mobile atm so I can't fully answer questions in the right and tested way, which is for me the reason I'm keeping to comments

Comment: Yeah but for the first to be false you need to iterate the entire list. The second can already be false after evaluating the first element. So if boyh conditions are expected to return true with the same chance this should definately be provable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the typical business problem described here is comparing 2 collections and looking for missing, matching and different records, the latter (different - but not missing - records) being what is reported in the question

If you want both a functional and an efficient solution you can use the `Enumerable.Aggregate` LINQ extension method, as suggested in a similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58584017/11323942), wrapped inside the external `Where` over the first collection `list1`.

```
(bool allVerified, bool anyVerified) = 
    list2.Aggregate( 
        ValueTuple.Create(true, false), 
        (tuple, item) => ValueTuple.Create(
            tuple.Item1 && !(Cond1(item1,item) && Cond2(item1,item)), 
            tuple.Item2 || Cond1(item1, item)) );
return allVerified && anyVerified;
```

Full snippet [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gLc36D) here.