# Memory efficient GroupBy + Aggregation using Rx

Tags: c#, system.reactive, memory-efficient

I have a sequence of items, and want to group them by a key and calculate several aggregations for each key.

The number of items is large, but the number of distinct keys is small.

A toy example:

```
static List<(string Key, decimal Sum, int Count)> GroupStats(
    IEnumerable<(string Key, decimal Value)> items)
{
    return items
        .GroupBy(x => x.Key)
        .Select(g => (
            Key : g.Key,
            Sum : g.Sum(x => x.Value),
            Count : g.Count()
        ))
        .ToList();
}
```

Using Linq's `GroupBy` has the unfortunate consequence that it'll need to load all the items into memory.

An imperative implementation would only consume memory proportional to the number of distinct keys, but I'm wondering if there is a nicer solution.

Reactive Extension's "push" approach should theoretically enable low memory grouping as well, but I didn't find a way to escape from `IObservable` to materialize the actual values. I'm also open to other elegant solutions (besides the obvious imperative implementation).

Comment: What is "large" in this context? Some people seem to think that 1k items are many. And why do you want to use GroupBy in a context where it is inefficient? Using a dictionary to sum items should be fairly simple, not much more code, and avoid your efficiency concerns. Keep in mind, LINQ is for *convenience*, it is not a silver bullet, especially not where things like performance is a concern.

Comment: More than I'm willing to keep in RAM, let's say a billion. CPU performance isn't a big concern, since loading the data is slower than transforming it with LINQ/Rx. I know how to write this imperatively using a dictionary, but I'd like to explore alternative solutions before deciding to go that way.

Comment: This question might be slightly relevant: [How to check an IEnumerable for multiple conditions with a single enumeration without buffering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58578480/how-to-check-an-ienumerable-for-multiple-conditions-with-a-single-enumeration-wi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
static IList<(string Key, decimal Sum, int Count)> GroupStats(
    IEnumerable<(string Key, decimal Value)> source)
{
    return source
        .ToObservable()
        .GroupBy(x => x.Key)
        .Select(g => (
            Key: g.Key,
            Sum: g.Sum(x => x.Value).PublishLast().AutoConnect(0),
            Count: g.Count().PublishLast().AutoConnect(0)
        ))
        .ToList()
        .Wait()
        .Select(e => (e.Key, e.Sum.Wait(), e.Count.Wait()))
        .ToArray();
}
```

- With the `ToObservable` operator, the `IEnumerable<T>`¹ source is converted to an `IObservable<T>` sequence.
- The `GroupBy` converts the `IObservable<T>` to an `IObservable<IGroupedObservable<string, T>>`.
- The `Select` converts each `IGroupedObservable<string, T>` to a `(string, IObservable<decimal>, IObservable<int>)`. The `PublishLast` is used in order to remember the last (and only) value emitted by the `Sum` and `Count` operators. The `AutoConnect(0)` subscribes to these subsequences immediately when they are emitted.
- The `ToList` converts the `IObservable<T>` to an `IObservable<IList<T>>`. The outer observable will emit a single list when it is completed.
- The `Wait` waits synchronously for the outer observable to complete, and to emit the single list. This is where all the work happens. Until this point the `source` sequence has not been enumerated. The `Wait` subscribes to the observable that has been constructed so far, which triggers subscriptions to the underlying observables, and eventually triggers the enumeration of the `source`. All the calculations are performed synchronously during the subscriptions, on the current thread. So the verb "wait" doesn't describe accurately what's happening here.
- The next `Select` converts each `(string, IObservable<decimal>, IObservable<int>)` to a `(string, decimal, int)`, by waiting the subsequences. These subsequences have already completed at this point, and their single output is stored inside the `PublishLast`. So these inner `Wait` invocations are not triggering any serious work. All the heavy work has already been done on the previous step.
- Finally the `ToArray` converts the `IEnumerable<(string, decimal, int)>` to an array of `(string, decimal, int)`, which is the output of the `GroupStats` method.

¹ <sub>I am using the `T` as placeholder for a complex `ValueTuple`, so that the explanation is not overly verbose.</sub>

---

**Update:** The Rx `ToObservable` operator has [quite a lot of overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60987491/why-is-ienumerable-toobservable-so-slow), because it has to support the Rx [scheduling infrastructure](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/15_SchedulingAndThreading.html#Schedulers).
You can replace it with the `ToObservableHypersonic` below, and achieve a speed-up of around 5x:

```
public static IObservable<TSource> ToObservableHypersonic<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    return Observable.Create<TSource>(observer =>
    {
        foreach (var item in source) observer.OnNext(item);
        observer.OnCompleted();
        return Disposable.Empty;
    });
}
```

I should also mention an alternative to the `PublishLast`+`AutoConnect(0)` combination, which is to convert the subsequences to tasks with the `ToTask` method. It has the same effect: the subsequences are subscribed immediately and their last value is memorized.

```
    Sum: g.Sum(x => x.Value).ToTask(),
    Count: g.Count().ToTask()
//...
.Select(e => (e.Key, e.Sum.Result, e.Count.Result))
```

Comment: That's definitely a bit more complex than I expected, especially the `.PublishLast().AutoConnect(0)` part.

Comment: I'll accept this answer, since it's what I asked for and has a great explanation. But I'll stay with the imperative implementation for now, since it's much easier to understand and doesn't require explanation.

Comment: @Nik yep, it's definitely not a walk in the park. If you don't know in depth how the Rx library works internally, it's highly unlikely that you'll be successful at doing synchronous processing with it, which is certainly not this library's [intended purpose](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/01_WhyRx.html#WhenRx)!

Comment: @Nik I updated the answer with an example of using the `.ToTask()` instead of the `.PublishLast().AutoConnect(0)`, and with a performance optimization for the `.ToObservable()`.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this is a simpler implementation:

```
static IList<(string Key, decimal Sum, int Count)> GroupStats(
    IEnumerable<(string Key, decimal Value)> source)
{
    return source
        .ToObservable(Scheduler.Immediate)
        .GroupBy(x => x.Key)
        .SelectMany(
            g => g.Aggregate(
                (Sum: 0m, Count: 0),
                (a, x) => (a.Sum + x.Value, a.Count + 1)), 
            (x, y) => (Key: x.Key, Sum: y.Sum, Count: y.Count)) 
        .ToList()
        .Wait();
}
```

Or better, a non-blocking version:

```
static async Task<IList<(string Key, decimal Sum, int Count)>> GroupStats(
    IEnumerable<(string Key, decimal Value)> source)
{
    return await source
        .ToObservable(Scheduler.Immediate)
        .GroupBy(x => x.Key)
        .SelectMany(
            g => g.Aggregate(
                (Sum: 0m, Count: 0),
                (a, x) => (a.Sum + x.Value, a.Count + 1)), 
            (x, y) => (Key: x.Key, Sum: y.Sum, Count: y.Count)) 
        .ToList();
}
```

If I run the async version with this source:

```
var source = new[]
{
    (Key: "a", Value: 1m),
    (Key: "c", Value: 2m),
    (Key: "b", Value: 3m),
    (Key: "b", Value: 4m),
    (Key: "c", Value: 5m),
    (Key: "c", Value: 6m),
};

var output = await GroupStats(source);
```

I get this output:

[image: output]

Comment: *`(a, x) => (a.Sum + x.Value, a.Count + 1))`* -- I think that the whole point of this exercise is to exploit the functionality of the Rx operators, instead of doing manually the math. Otherwise it would be even simpler to stay in the realm of the `IEnumerable<T>` and the LINQ (maybe with the help of MoreLinq). Also both the `Wait` and the `await` versions are most likely doing the same thing. The calculations are performed on the current thread. Nothing really asynchronous is happening.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - I thought the idea was to avoid having the entire enumerable in memory. This avoids that. Also the `SelectMany` should be doing things concurrently. And the choice of `Aggregate` was to avoid unnecessary subscriptions.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - It'd just need a `.ObserveOn(Scheduler.Default)` before the `Aggregate` to get this working concurrenctly.

Comment: *"I thought the idea was to avoid having the entire enumerable in memory"* -- Oh, yes, you are right, I forgot that. The LINQ `GroupBy` operator stores everything in memory before handing the groupings for further processing.

Comment: If I wanted to offload the calculations to a `ThreadPool` thread, I would probably prefer to wrap the whole thing in an `await Task.Run(() => /* ... */)`. Messing with the Rx schedulers is really for the priesthood. 