# The Observable.Repeat is unstoppable, is it a bug or a feature?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, rx.net

I noticed something strange with the behavior of the [`Repeat`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/repeat.html) operator, when the source observable's notifications are synchronous. The resulting observable cannot be stopped with a subsequent [`TakeWhile`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/takewhile.html) operator, and apparently continues running forever. For demonstration I created a source observable that produces a single value, which it is incremented on every subscription. The first subscriber gets the value 1, the second gets the value 2 etc:

```
int incrementalValue = 0;
var incremental = Observable.Create<int>(async o =>
{
    await Task.CompletedTask;
    //await Task.Yield();

    Thread.Sleep(100);
    var value = Interlocked.Increment(ref incrementalValue);
    o.OnNext(value);
    o.OnCompleted();
});
```

Then I attached the operators `Repeat`, `TakeWhile` and `LastAsync` to this observable, so that the program will wait until the composed observable produces its last value:

```
incremental.Repeat()
    .Do(new CustomObserver("Checkpoint A"))
    .TakeWhile(item => item <= 5)
    .Do(new CustomObserver("Checkpoint B"))
    .LastAsync()
    .Do(new CustomObserver("Checkpoint C"))
    .Wait();
Console.WriteLine($"Done");

class CustomObserver : IObserver<int>
{
    private readonly string _name;
    public CustomObserver(string name) => _name = name;
    public void OnNext(int value) => Console.WriteLine($"{_name}: {value}");
    public void OnError(Exception ex) => Console.WriteLine($"{_name}: {ex.Message}");
    public void OnCompleted() => Console.WriteLine($"{_name}: Completed");
}
```

Here is the output of this program:

```xml
Checkpoint A: 1
Checkpoint B: 1
Checkpoint A: 2
Checkpoint B: 2
Checkpoint A: 3
Checkpoint B: 3
Checkpoint A: 4
Checkpoint B: 4
Checkpoint A: 5
Checkpoint B: 5
Checkpoint A: 6
Checkpoint B: Completed
Checkpoint C: 5
Checkpoint C: Completed
Checkpoint A: 7
Checkpoint A: 8
Checkpoint A: 9
Checkpoint A: 10
Checkpoint A: 11
Checkpoint A: 12
Checkpoint A: 13
Checkpoint A: 14
Checkpoint A: 15
Checkpoint A: 16
Checkpoint A: 17
...
```

It never ends! Although the `LastAsync` has produced its value and has completed, the `Repeat` operator keeps spinning!

This happens only if the source observable notifies its subscribers synchronously. For example after uncommenting the line  `//await Task.Yield();`, the program behaves as expected:

```xml
Checkpoint A: 1
Checkpoint B: 1
Checkpoint A: 2
Checkpoint B: 2
Checkpoint A: 3
Checkpoint B: 3
Checkpoint A: 4
Checkpoint B: 4
Checkpoint A: 5
Checkpoint B: 5
Checkpoint A: 6
Checkpoint B: Completed
Checkpoint C: 5
Checkpoint C: Completed
Done
```

The `Repeat` operator stops spinning, although it does not report completion (my guess is that it has been unsubscribed).

Is there any way to achieve consistent behavior from the `Repeat` operator, irrespective of the type of notifications it receives (sync or async)?

.NET Core 3.0, C# 8, System.Reactive 4.3.2, Console Application

Comment: I do keep saying that `Observable.Create` is bad...

Comment: Well, it's more to do with the `Scheduler.Immediate`. Change the scheduler to `incremental.ObserveOn(Scheduler.Default).Repeat()` and see what happens.

Comment: I suspect you're locking up the thread that's needed to unsubscribe.

Comment: @Enigmativity it's not related to `Observable.Create`. The problem persists with this implementation as well: `var incremental = Observable.Defer(() => Observable.Return(++incrementalValue));`

Comment: Yes, you're right. However `Observable.Create` makes it too easy to create observables with this problem.

Comment: @Enigmativity with `ObserveOn(Scheduler.Default)` the notifications are received from various threads, essentially mimicking my test with `await Task.Yield()` inside the producer. But I checked another option: `ObserveOn(Scheduler.CurrentThread)` that seems to solve cleanly the problem! With this option the program works as expected, and everything happens in a single thread. Are there any drawbacks with `ObserveOn(Scheduler.CurrentThread)` that I should be aware of?

Comment: The problem is also solved with `SubscribeOn(Scheduler.CurrentThread)` before `Repeat`, God knows why!

Comment: From memory `Scheduler.CurrentThread` uses the trampoline to schedule on the current thread (i.e. current context) so it isn't running immediately and unblocks the thread. Otherwise with `Scheduler.Immediate` you run the risk of deadlocks.

Comment: @Enigmativity that what I was guessing, but a Console application has no synchronization context, so it's puzzling.

Comment: You should look at the source for the `System.Reactive.Concurrency` namespace. That'll make your eye water. They do so many tricks in there to make Rx work. There's a sync context in there somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might expect an implementation of `Repeat` to feature the `OnCompleted` notification, but it turns [it's implemented](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/b468268fe4f068eef04a4e509dc9449820313665/Rx.NET/Source/src/System.Reactive/Linq/QueryLanguage.Single.cs#L226) in terms of `Concat`-ing an infinite stream.

```
    public static IObservable<TSource> Repeat<TSource>(this IObservable<TSource> source) =>
        RepeatInfinite(source).Concat();

    private static IEnumerable<T> RepeatInfinite<T>(T value)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            yield return value;
        }
    }
```

With that responsibility shifted to `Concat` - we can create a simplified version (the gory implementation details are in `TailRecursiveSink.cs`). This still keeps on spinning unless there's a different execution context provided by `await Task.Yield()`.

```
public static IObservable<T> ConcatEx<T>(this IEnumerable<IObservable<T>> enumerable) =>
    Observable.Create<T>(observer =>
    {
        var check = new BooleanDisposable();

        IDisposable loopRec(IScheduler inner, IEnumerator<IObservable<T>> enumerator)
        {
            if (check.IsDisposed)
                return Disposable.Empty;

            if (enumerator.MoveNext()) //this never returns false
                return enumerator.Current.Subscribe(
                    observer.OnNext,
                    () => inner.Schedule(enumerator, loopRec) //<-- starts next immediately
                );
            else
                return inner.Schedule(observer.OnCompleted); //this never runs
        }

        Scheduler.Immediate.Schedule(enumerable.GetEnumerator(), loopRec); //this runs forever
        return check;
    });
```

Being an infinite stream, `enumerator.MoveNext()` always returns true, so the other branch never runs - that's expected; it's not our problem.

When the `o.OnCompleted()` is called, it immediately schedules the next iterative loop in
`Schedule(enumerator, loopRec)` which synchronously calls the next `o.OnCompleted()`, and it continues ad infinitum - there's no point where it can escape this recursion.

If you have a context switch with `await Task.Yield()`, then `Schedule(enumerator, loopRec)` exits immediately, and `o.OnCompleted()` is called non-synchronously.

`Repeat` and `Concat` use the current thread to do work without changing the context - that's not incorrect behavior, but when the same context is used to push notifications as well, it can lead to deadlocks or being caught in a 
perpetual trampoline.

**Annotated Call Stack**

```
[External Code] 
Main.AnonymousMethod__0(o) //o.OnCompleted();
[External Code] 
ConcatEx.__loopRec|1(inner, enumerator) //return enumerator.Current.Subscribe(...)
[External Code] 
ConcatEx.AnonymousMethod__2() //inner.Schedule(enumerator, loopRec)
[External Code] 
Main.AnonymousMethod__0(o) //o.OnCompleted();
[External Code] 
ConcatEx.__loopRec|1(inner, enumerator) //return enumerator.Current.Subscribe(...)
[External Code] 
ConcatEx.AnonymousMethod__0(observer) //Scheduler.Immediate.Schedule(...)
[External Code] 
Main(args) //incremental.RepeatEx()...
```

Comment: Thanks Asti. I couldn't hope for a more thorough answer!

Comment: @TheodorZoulias You're welcome! I used the experience from digging through the source for the other question.

Comment: Sorry I didn't attempt this earlier! It looked to me like some conclusion was reached in the comments.

Comment: Yes, we figured out the workaround of using `Scheduler.CurrentThread`, but what caused the default behavior was still a mystery. 

Comment: Ah, changing ` Scheduler.Immediate` to `Scheduler.CurrentThread` in the `ConcatEx` implementation fixes the problem.

Comment: But having `Repeat` run on `Scheduler.CurrentThread` might lead to a host of other problems. I mean in general.

Comment: Yeap, the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61041484/why-does-repeated-enumerable-to-observable-conversion-block) about the problems of `ToObservable().ToEnumerable().ToObservable()` was quite revealing. The RX abstraction starts leaking if you push it too much!

Comment: Agree. Most of the times Rx is "don't worry about concurrency", but when you push anything to its limits, the law of leaky abstractions catches up.

Comment: If the mystery was solved, could you mark this as answered?